# How to relevel a factor variable with over 500 levels efficiently in R

Tags: r, startswith

I haven't been able to find any answers to this specific problem:

I have a factor variable with over 500 levels, that I need to relevel to just 2 levels (1/0.)

Many of the levels start with the same character string e.g. "Woman's mother or sister:"

Is there a way to use starts_with to relevel all of these levels at the same time, instead of doing one by one as I have been doing with this code:

```
   levels(DF1$MedicalCondition)[levels(DF1$MedicalCondition) == "Woman's mother or sister: sister"] <- "1"
```

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tidyselect::starts_with` is specifically written for use on column names within `dplyr`-type functions, but you can use the base R `startsWith`:

```
levels(DF1$MedicalCondition)[
  startsWith(levels(DF1$MedicalCondition), "Woman's mother or sister")
] <- "1"
```

You can also use general regex patterns with `grepl` or `stringr::str_detect`, which can be very powerful.

Comment: Is there something similar for contains() in base R? For any level containing a particular string?

Comment: `grepl` with the `fixed = TRUE` argument is basically the same as `contains`.